# Gaps between rows with MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I'm adding a `JCheckbox` and two `JPanels` to another `JPanel` with `MigLayout`, each in a different line. The problem is that the gaps between the rows are 1-2 cm, and I don't want a gap between them. I tried to use grow to fill the space, but it only fills it horizontally, not vertically.

Hope that someone knows how to fix this. I'm a newbie so I hope that you can explain in an "easy to get"-way.

Thanks

Comment: Help us help you - show your code :)

Answer (score 3):

In MigLayout there's a layout constraint (the first of the three strings in the definition of the layout) for gaps: `gap`, and its vertical variant `gapy`, so...

```
new MigLayout("gapy 0...", "[...]", "[...]");
```

Answer (score 0):

MigLayout uses standard-sized gaps between components if you do not explicitliy change them.
If you want to delete these gaps you can set `0lp!` between the lines in your row definition, e.g. `MigLayout("", "[]", "[my checkbox row definitions]0lp![my first panel row definitions]0lp![my second panel row definitions]")`

Hope that's what you mean ;-)

Kind regards,

Turn

Answer (score 0):

Do this where you declare your MigLayout

`MigLayout mg = new MigLayout("", "", "1");`